# node.js + socket.io chat application

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I develop an instant messaging system for my site and i have 2 problems. First is that console.log doesnt work, so i cant trace the script executing. The second is that i cant see the incoming messages, only my own messages that I type, and messages are not added to the database. Possibly the problem is with mysql requests or mysql connect. Please help me to resolve these problems

server

```
var http = require('http');

var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'lc',
});


var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080); 

/*io.set('log level', 0);*/


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {


function escapeHtml(str) {
  return String(str)
      .replace(/&/g, "&")
      .replace(/</g, "<")
      .replace(/>/g, ">")
      .replace(/"/g, "")
      .replace(/'/g, "'")
       .replace(/\//g, "⁄");
}


socket.on('connect_user', function(login,password, idUserGet){
    var sql    = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ' + connection.escape(login) + ' AND password = ' + connection.escape(password) + ' ';
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
        if(rows.length > 0) {

            socket.userGet = idUserGet;
            socket.userSend = rows[0].id;


            console.log(socket.userSend+' has been logined ');
            socket.join(socket.userSend);


            socket.user = rows[0].login;
        } 
    });



socket.on( 'msg', function(msg) {
    // htmlencode
    msg = escapeHtml(msg); 

    // Unixtime
    milliseconds = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    var post  = {user_send: socket.userSend, user_get: socket.userGet, text: msg, date: milliseconds};
    query = connection.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
        update = connection.query(sql);
    });





    console.log(' usersend id:  ' +socket.userSend +'  user get:  ' + socket.userGet + ' ');
     socket.broadcast.to(socket.userGet).json.emit('incMsg',{'userSend': socket.userSend, 'name': socket.user, 'text': msg, 'time': time })
});
});
});
```

client

```
function tpl(t) {
html = ' <div class="msg>';
html += '    <div class="img"><img src="'+t.img+'" /></div>';
html += '    <div class="info">';
html += '         <div class="name"><a href="#">' + t.name + '</a></div>';
html += '        <div class="text">'+t.text+'</div>';
html += '    </div>';
html += '</div>';

return html;
}

$(window).load(function() {
var milliseconds = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') != -1) {
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {'transports': ['xhr-polling']});
} else {
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
}

socket.on('connect', function () {
    var id = '<?=$MY_FRIEND_ID;?>'; 

    img = $("#userGet img").attr('src');
    $("#userGet img").attr('src',img);

    $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight+9999999);
    socket.id = id;
    socket.emit('adduser', '<?=$MY_LOGIN;?>','<?=$MY_PASS;?>',id);



    socket.on('incMsg', function (msg) {

        if(msg.userSend == id) {
            msg.text = msg.text.replace(/(\n(\r)?)/g, ' <br/>'); 


            if(msg.userSend == '<?=$MY_LOGIN;?>') msg.img = '<?=$avatar;?>'; else msg.img = '/img/users/<?=$MY_FRIEND_AVATAR;?>';

            html = tpl(msg);


            $('#messages').append(html);
            $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight+9999999);
        }
    });


   $('#input').keydown(function(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && !(event.shiftKey) ) {

            input = $(this).val();


            var newDate = new Date();
            if(newDate.getMinutes() < 10) getMinute = '0'+newDate.getMinutes(); else getMinute = newDate.getMinutes();
            dateString = newDate.getHours() + ":";
            dateString += getMinute + ":";
            dateString += newDate.getSeconds();

            var msg = {
              name:  '<?=$MY_LOGIN;?>',
              text: input.replace(/(\n(\r)?)/g, ' <br/>'), 
              time: dateString,
              img: '<?=$avatar;?>' 
            };


            html = tpl(msg);

            $('#messages').append(html);
            $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight+9999999);

            socket.emit( 'msg', input);
            $(this).val('');

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
});
```

Comment: The problem is that i cant get login and password from database, queries dont work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't actually connecting to mysql.

Try this:

```js
/* requiring modules */

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'lc',
});

connection.connect(function(err){
  //can do something with an error 
});

/* your code*/
```